# In openpop net when read email it's get an error "The input is not valid base64 string as it contains non-base 64 character,"

Tags: c#, gmail, tls1.2, starttls, openpop

I use openpop net library for delete and forward email, normal mail(without TLS protocol) contains are readable. But which mails are sent through protocol(TLS) are not readable, that give me an error.

> "The input is not valid base64 string as it contains non-base 64 character, more than two padding character or an illeagal character".

Comment: The error seems fairly explicit. Anyway you have shown no code, its not possible to answer this question without guessing

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here, and guess that the input is not valid base64 string as it contains non-base 64 character, more than two padding character or an illegal character. Without code or example data, that's the best we can probably do...